# Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using MVC and Entity Framework.  I've created a class in my model folder with this code below.  I keep getting the error message above with both queries below.  I know there is a known issue on referencing non-scalar variables, but I'm not sure how to implement a workaround:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#Y1442

```
private MovieLibraryDBEntities movieLibraryDBEntitiesContext;

public int getNumberOfEntriesReserved()
{
    return (from m in movieLibraryDBEntitiesContext.Movies
            where m.CheckedOut.Equals(1)
            select m).Count();

    //return movieLibraryDBEntitiesContext.Movies
    //  .Where(e => e.CheckedOut.Equals(1))
    //  .Select (e => e.Title).Count();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You cannot use `m.CheckedOut.Equals(1)` in linq-to-entities query. Use `m.CheckedOut == 1` but `CheckedOut` must be `integer`.

Comment: Thanks!  This is actually a bit field in SQL Server so I used this instead and it worked:  where (m.CheckedOut == true)

Comment: equals works fine in linq to entities. I use it all the time.  e.g. `.Where(r => r.EmployeeName.Equals(employeeName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

Comment: Thank you. It is one of those things that are almost impossible to find with the error message.

Answer (score 3):

This is an older question. I had the same problem when trying to filter a nullable column using the IQueryable interface. I solved the problem by first checking to see if the object had a value and then checking the value.

```
widgets = widgets.Where(x => x.ID.HasValue.Equals(true) &&  x.ID.Value.Equals(widgetID));
```

Answer (score 1):

same issue using `Any()`
i had to change my where clause to search on primitive types, for me int

so this

```
where order.User == user
```

becomes this

```
where order.User.UserId == user.UserId
```

There is a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx) explaining the quirk.