# LINQ related error "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, linq, icollection

I have some code that is selecting some values from my database. I have a IQueryable of requests, that contains a ICollection of rooms.

I want to get a `List<ICollection<rooms>>`. I have tried the following and i recieve the above error.

Any ideas??

```
public ActionResult _roomChecker(checkRooms JSONdata){
        var rooms = db.rooms.Include(r=>r.building).Include(r=>r.facilities);
        rooms = rooms.Where(r => r.capacity >= JSONdata.capacity);
        if (JSONdata.type != "Any")
        {
            rooms = rooms.Where(r => r.roomType.Equals(JSONdata.type));
        }
        if (JSONdata.park != "Any")
        {
            rooms = rooms.Where(r => r.building.park.Equals(JSONdata.park));
        }

        if (JSONdata.facilities != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < JSONdata.facilities.Length; i++)
            {
                rooms = rooms.Where(r => r.facilities.Any(f => f.facilityName.Equals(JSONdata.facilities[i])));

            }
        }

        var proposedRequest = db.requests.Include(r => r.rooms);
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r=>r.booked.Equals(1));
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r => r.roundID.Equals(JSONdata.roundID));
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r => r.day.Equals(JSONdata.day));
        proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(s => s.start < JSONdata.start + JSONdata.length && s.start + s.length > JSONdata.start);
        int[] standardWeeks = new int[12] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
        var containsStandard = standardWeeks.Intersect(JSONdata.weeks);
        if (containsStandard.Count()!=0)
        {
            proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r => r.weeks_request.Any(f => JSONdata.weeks.Contains(f.week)) || r.weeks.Equals(1));
        }
        else {
            proposedRequest = proposedRequest.Where(r => r.weeks_request.Any(f => JSONdata.weeks.Contains(f.week)));
        }

    //ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE BELOW

        List<ICollection<room>> bookedRooms = proposedRequest.Select(r => r.rooms).ToList();


        var deptRooms = db.rooms.Include(r => r.building).Include(r => r.facilities).Where(r => r.belongsTo.Equals(JSONdata.deptCode));

        roomCheckerObject suitableRooms = new roomCheckerObject();
        suitableRooms.code = JSONdata.deptCode;
        suitableRooms.roomNo = JSONdata.roomNo;
        suitableRooms.RequestNo = JSONdata.RequestNo;
        if(rooms.Count() >0){
            suitableRooms.rooms = rooms.ToList();
            var buildings = rooms.Select(r => r.building).Distinct();
            suitableRooms.buildings = buildings.ToList();
        }
        if(bookedRooms.Count() >0){
            suitableRooms.bookedRooms = bookedRooms;
        }

        if(deptRooms.Count() >0){
            suitableRooms.deptRooms = deptRooms.ToList();
        }
        return PartialView(suitableRooms);}
```

Comment: @MattSull r.belongsTo is just a String, but it is a foreign key. JSONdata is a ViewModel

Comment: Are you sure the exception is being thrown on the line `List<ICollection<room>>`? This error can happen with Linq to entities when you use `.Equals()` instead of `==`, which is why I ask.

Comment: I'm not sure, but could it be that you need to use SelectMany() to flatten the list instead of .Select()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of difficult to say what exactly is causing the error but I can see 3 possible culprits:

1) You're using `.Equals()` with a Linq to entities (L2E) query. This can cause problems, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923543/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-system-object-only-primitive-types).

2) You say the error occurs on the line where `List<ICollection<room>>` is declared. On this line you call `.ToList()` for the first time in any of L2E statements. Only now will your L2E query be executed ([see EF Query Execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738633%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) against the database meaning possibly any error (using `.Equals()`) in a previous L2E statement could throw the exception.

3) Does `proposedRequest.Select(r => r.rooms).ToList();` really return an `List<ICollection<room>>`? Try using `.SelectMany()` (though this may have undesirable effects) or for a sanity check change `List<ICollection<room>>` to `var` to see what the query will return.

Comment: My inclination is that it's part of Select vs SelectMany since it is a collection of collections. But I like your _sanity check_ idea the best

Comment: I went through and changed all my .Equals() to == just for the sake of saving potential errors. This initially didnt solve the problem, so i carried on changed what you had said and nothing worked. I then spotted one last pesky .Equals and changed it, no errors now :) Thanks for your help :)