# LINQ TO ENTITY cannot compare to enumeration types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums, linq-to-entities

Below are the enum Leaves

```
public enum Leaves
{
    Annual = 0,
    Medical = 1,
    Hospitalization = 2,
    Unpaid = 3
}
```

Below is the linq query

```
public ActionResult ApproveLeave(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return View();

        LeaveApplication leaveApplication = db.LeaveApplication.Find(id);

        if (leaveApplication == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        leaveApplication.Status = "Approved";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(leaveApplication).State = EntityState.Modified;

            Leaves leavesType = (Leaves)Enum.Parse(typeof(Leaves), leaveApplication.LeaveType.ToString());

            var lb = (from t in db.LeaveBalance
                      select t)
                      .Where(t => t.LeaveType == leavesType && t.Profileid.Equals(id))
                      .FirstOrDefault();

            lb.Taken++;
            lb.Balance--;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I have even try using the Leaves.Annual but it doesnt work.
LINQ QUERY THROWS FOLLOWING EXCEPTION :

> System.NotSupportedException HResult=0x80131515 Message=Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923543/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-system-object-only-primitive-types)

Comment: As a side note, your `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is pointless - the only parameter in the method is an `int?` so `ModelState` will not be invalid

Comment: So ModelState.Isvalid is base on the parameter of the method i pass in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Equals` is not supported in Linq2ToEntity you should use the double equal instead:

```
var lb = (from t in db.LeaveBalance select t)
  .Where(t => t.LeaveType == leavesType && t.Profileid == id)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Assuming that your Profileid is a int using the == should make it work without changing the logic or running into case issues.

Comment: It does support Equals, my previous code using Equals is working and is better when it come to compare string type value. Btw i solve it ,i just realise that my Profileid is a string type thats why it keeps throw exception. Your comment 'Assuming that my Profileid is a int' reminds me to check it. Thx for helping.

Comment: @lolipop In C# `Equals` and `==` will be the same for `string` and most other types.  The big difference is if the types don't match (I'd imagine you would have gotten a better error message with `==`).  Also for Linq to SQL it just gets translated to SQL anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not relevant with `Enum` type. You can't use `Equals` for Linq to entities. So, modify your query;

```
var lb = (from t in db.LeaveBalance
          select t)
          .Where(t => t.LeaveType == leavesType && t.Profileid == id)
          .FirstOrDefault();
```